# i am not able to parse a json into tableview

Tags: json, xcode, swift3

`{
1: {
cityname_EN: "Munich",
cityname_DE: "München",
country: "DE",
image: "http://res.muenchen-p.de/fl_progressive,q_65/.imaging/stk/responsive/teaser300/dms/sw/bg/muenchen_in_bildern_neu/sehenswuerdigkeiten/top_20_sehenswuerdigkeiten/img/marienplatz/document/marienplatz.jpg",
text_EN: "Munich is a nice city blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla",
text_DE: "München in Bayern ist schön la blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla",
lat: 48.137269,
long: 11.574727
},
2: {
cityname_EN: "Berlin",
cityname_DE: "Berlin",
country: "DE",
image: "http://p5.focus.de/img/incoming/crop4074346/5772711184-w1200-h627-o-q75-p5/original-1-.jpg",
text_EN: "Berlin is a nice city blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla",
text_DE: "Berlin ist eine la blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla blabla",
lat: 48.137269,
long: 11.574727
}
}`

My json link is in the code.

**I am having a problem parsing this json data into a dictionary string and then show it on the table view just the county names**

```
import UIKit

import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var show: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var arrRes = [[String: Any]]()

    var d1 : [String:String] = [:]



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UserDefaults.standard.set(array, forKey: "name")


        Alamofire.request("https://www.best-cityguide.com/data/citylist.json").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
            if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
               // let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
                if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
                    let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

                    if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["1"].dictionaryObject {
                        self.arrRes = resData as! [[String: Any]]

                        print(resData)
                    }
                    else {
                        print("none")
                    }
                    if self.arrRes.count > 0 {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }




    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int

    {

        return arrRes.count

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

       // let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("jsonCell")!
        var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = dict["country"] as? String




        return cell
    }   

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

This is my code in swift can any body hepl me with this

i think the problem is in `if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["1"].dictionaryObject {
                        self.arrRes = resData as! [[String: Any]]` these two line

Comment: wouldn't just 1x `bla` be enough to show here?

Comment: The code does not compile. Where does `array` come from? And why twice   the check `responseData.result.value != nil` ? By the way you don't need to wrap `if` expressions in parentheses in Swift. If `resData` is a *dictionaryObject* it can't be `[[String: Any]]` (an **array**).

Comment: ok but i am new here can you guide me with the correct code  i have been stuck here from days now

Comment: A dictionary is `[String: Any]`.

Comment: you mean this 'var arrRes = [[String: Any]]()' should be  var arrRes = [String: Any]()

Comment: Basically yes (and `resData as! [String: Any]`) because the object is a dictionary, but actually you need an array as data source. So keep the declaration of `arrRes` and write `self.arrRes.append(resData as! [String: Any])`

Comment: i have put this solution and still giving an error

Comment: **W h a t** error?

Comment: **Value of type '[String : Any]' has no member 'append'**

Comment: I meant to keep `var arrRes = [[String: Any]]()`

Comment: And Another error also

Comment: **var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]**

Comment: Please read my comments carefully and please try to understand the difference between dictionary and array

Comment: oh waoooo it worked error goes and data is loaded in the table

Comment: Brother i want to chat with you on facebook or any where else i need help i am very new to ios and want to learn    you look very great with this and i want your help is you dont mind

Comment: can i contact you  i will not take more time of you

Comment: I don't use facebook at all and I don't want to become a personal tutor, no offense.

Comment: ok brother no problem i am glad you helped me here with this

Comment: i have an other think also some body said to me that this is not a valid Json  is that so ?

Comment: If the parsing works it has to be valid.

Comment: ok  and how can i have both of this **dictionaryObject** data into one Dictionary   like  ** if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["2","1"].dictionaryObject** will this work